# How can I copy all OPEN VLC media files into a directory?

Tags: batch, vlc-media-player, media, open

Sometimes I'll open six or more random video files using VLC media player.  These videos reside in various directories on my hard drive.  Is there some way to **copy** all of these **OPEN** videos into a new directory, and name that new directory with the current date?  Example: 2020-01-09 (year-month-date)
I was hoping for a batch file solution, but whatever works!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=using+vlc+to+copy+files

Comment: So. Where you planning create the folder 20-01-20? Would be In ..\user\videos\20-01-20?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the extension, use this:

```
@echo off
For /f "Tokens=2,3,4" %%a in ('date /t') do set d=%%a & set m=%%b & set y=%%c
md "%y%-%m%-%d%"
xcopy "Full path\*.extensionofvlcmediafiles" "%y%-%m%-%d%"
```